# How to declare a service with Angular5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I have an Angular service that looks like this

```
@Component({})
@Inject(ChromeDataService)
@Injectable()
export class MainDataService {

}
```

when I run `ng build --prod`, I get this error

> ERROR in : No template specified for component MainDataService

my only guess is that an Angular service does not need to be a component? So I removed the `@Component` annotation, but then I get this:

> ERROR in : Unexpected value 'MainDataService in
>   /home/.../main.ts'
>   declared by the module 'SharedModule in
>   /home/.../src/app/shared.module.ts'.
>   Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Uh, how do I create a service in Angular5?

Comment: your service only needs the @Injectable() decorator

Comment: yeah I guess so, uh want some points add an answer thx!

Comment: yeah I guess I meant decorator, not annotation

Answer (score 2):

To use an angular service properly you only need `injectable()`

Here's an example

```
@Injectable()
export class myService {
 //some logic
}
```

then in your `app.module` or in a feature module you add the service in the `providers` array and to have the angular DI handle the service for you.

```
@Component({
usual stuff with template, selector, css})
export class someComponent {
constructor(private myService: MyService){}
}
```

The constructor will tell angular to auto-magically inject the service you need in.

Answer (score 0):

your service only needs the @Injectable() decorator.like this

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import {Router} from '@angular/router'


@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}


}
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

That's how I declare services in Angular:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
     ...
}
```

I think you only need `@Injectable` decorator. Maybe your problem comes from `shared.module.ts`.

Comment: It isn't different from my answer.

Comment: sorry @MikeTung I didn't see your answer when I began to write.